# Changing content of text document in same folder as project through code inside the project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to change content of a eg. text document in the same folder as your project through code inside the project?
Using Visual Studio Community 2022
Using Template: Windows Forms App(.NET Framework)

I tried searching the problem but couldn't find anything.

Comment: There is no project. There's an application. Your project is the source code. You compile that into an executable and that's what you run in the debugger and that's what you deploy to other machines.

Comment: As for the issue, what's the actual issue? Are you saying that you don't know how to edit a text file? Are you saying that you don't know how to determine the path of the folder containing your executable? They are two completely different things and so they don't belong in one question. Work out what it is that you actually can't do and ask about that specifically. If you have multiple issues then ask multiple questions, each one specific to an issue.

Comment: With regards to files in the program folder, whether they can be edited depends where they are and who the user is. You will almost certainly be able to edit such a file when debugging your app but, if you deploy that app to a Program Files folder on another machine, non-admin users will not be able to edit the file. Windows has lots of special folders for various purposes, including data for applications. You should generally be using one of those folders for editable files.